# How to add custom attributes to a Python list?

Tags: python, list, setattr, python-builtins

I'm trying to associate additional data with a Python list. Ideally, I'd like to add custom attributes to a list object, similar to how you'd add attributes to a custom class. For example:

```py
a = [1, 2, 4, 8]
a.x = "Hey!"  # I'd like this to work without errors
```

However, when I attempt this, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I understand that Python lists don't support adding arbitrary attributes out of the box. I also tried using `setattr`, but it gave me a similar error:

```py
setattr(a, "k", 98)  # Raises AttributeError
```

I cannot create a custom class `DummyList(list)` to work around this (for reasons). I also don't want to use some global variable that holds the attributes for the lists. Are there any workarounds to achieve this in Python?

Comment: What's the end goal? Beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: Why do you even need this?) Technically you can create a custom class inherited from the list and add functionality but it doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Let's put it this way: in decades of programming, I have never needed to add attributes to a list instance, nor otherwise needed to bend over backwards to make a builtin do something it's clearly not designed to do. There are probably other, better, more out-of-the-box ways to do what you need to.

Comment: What are the reasons for not creating a class? If it's because inheriting from the builtins is messy, you can use [`UserList`](//docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userlist-objects) instead.

Comment: @wjandrea I need to add some metadata to some lists. (These metadata are used elsewhere in my code to decide what should happen with these lists.) I cannot create custom classes because some code I don't want to fork is using `type` to directly check that the type of these objects is `list`. I am currently using a global dictionary with `id(some_list)` as keys, but I dislike this solution.

Comment: @HappyFace In that case I would customize the behavior of that third-party module by subclassing and overriding the method that performs the type validation. Please update your question with a minimized example of the offending code in question if you would like a more specific answer.

Comment: So you want to "smuggle" some metadata through a library together with your data, while the library doesn't explicitly support any such thing? And it's written in a hostile way that makes this smuggling of metadata difficult? Then yeah, I'd second the notion to subclass and override that library in a way that makes it possible to pass your own types with your own metadata through. If that proves too difficult because you'd need to override a ton of code, then I'd try to associate the data _externally_ somehow, not passing it through at all. We'll need code samples for concrete advice.

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with your current solution of using a global dict with list identities as keys. It may not be as elegant as an idealistic yet unfortunately unattainable list with a custom attribute, but is simple and effective, and may be the best alternative if too much code needs to be overriden to make the aforementioned override approach work.